# How long does Snowflake really maintain file load history?

Tags: metadata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Source #1 of 3 - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-load.html#load-metadata says -

> "Snowflake maintains detailed metadata for each table into which data
> is loaded ... This load metadata expires after 64 days..." followed by
> an explanation of the LOAD_UNCERTAIN_FILES copy option. This option
> tells Snowflake whether or not to load files whose metadata, being
> over 64 days old, has been purged.

#2 of 3 - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-copy.html#monitoring-files-staged-internally says -

> "Snowflake retains historical data for COPY INTO commands executed
> within the previous 14 days... Use the LOAD_HISTORY Information Schema
> view to retrieve the history of data loaded into tables using the COPY
> INTO command"

#3 of 3 - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/copy_history.html#copy-history-view says -

> "This Account Usage view can be used to query Snowflake data loading
> history for the last 365 days (1 year). The view displays load
> activity for both COPY INTO  statements and continuous data
> loading using Snowpipe. The view avoids the 10,000 row limitation of
> the LOAD_HISTORY View."

---

Question #1
#3 seems to supersede #2, as the duration is 365 days and it maintains metadata not only for bulk loads, but continuous loading as well. Also, apparently there's a row limit on #2.
The view in #3 is available only to the ACCOUNTADMIN role by default.
But if Snowflake does have the information for the last 365 days, why force the use of LOAD_UNCERTAIN_FILES after just 64 days?

Question #2
Aren't sources #1 and 2 inconsistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important number for behavior of copying files into tables is 64 days. If you run a `COPY INTO` command from a stage without limiting the files by a list or pattern, Snowflake will not reload a file it's loaded within the previous 64 days.

You can override that using FORCE = TRUE in the copy options, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#copy-options-copyoptions. That will make it load the files whether they're marked as loaded or not.

When the following three conditions are met, ***for the purposes of the COPY INTO command***, Snowflake does not know if a file has already been loaded or not:

- The file’s LAST_MODIFIED date (i.e. date when the file was staged) is
  older than 64 days.
- The initial set of data was loaded into the table more than 64 day
  earlier.
- If the file was already loaded successfully into the table, this
  event occurred more than 64 days earlier.

Under those conditions, the LOAD_UNCERTAIN_FILES option applies.

The other two times concern reporting, not behavior of the COPY INTO command. The 14 days is for the `LIST` or `LS` command information returned. The 365 days is for the data shared back from Snowflake to customers through the "snowflake" database. Data can take between 15 minutes and 3 hours to appear in this database depending on the view in question. It remains for 365 days after that.

Comment: Thanks @Greg Pavlik, your clarification of the 3-hour latency in the _snowflake_ database was helpful, and your restatement of the purpose behind the 3 interfaces as such.